# What options are there for embedding the Facebook Authorization Dialog in a custom modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using ASP.Net MVC3 and have a very basic web site that uses the server side flow to perform the Facebook authentication and authorization. Presently the login button is defined with the following HTML:

I am able to get the user redirected to Facebook where they login and authorize the permissions and the site does get redirected back to my controller with an authorization token that I can convert to an access token. I have the 2 following problems that I am trying to solve:

1) Within the anchor's href, I have the "....display=popup" and was hoping that would result in a popup but instead my entire page is redirected to Facebook. Is there a way to use the server side flow with some JS to make the authorization dialog as a popup without resorting to using the Facebook Javascript SDK?

2) Assuming I can show the Authorization dialog as a popup, is there a way to force it to show within a truly MODAL popup dialog such as a jQueryUI Dialog so we can add some content with it? I have seen sites that have the popup but it just dims the page but it doesn't enforce that the user to complete the authorization before clicking back on the page.

Any insight is much appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use the Facebook Like button or call FB.Login to create a popup. See the Facebook Javascript SDK for reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

2) This is not possible.